# S3 SlowDown: Please reduce your request rate exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a service that sends 10k PUT requests to S3 for every second. The S3 was able to handle those loads for several minutes but started to throw SlowDown exception after that. It slows down my service to an unacceptable rate.

I have read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) and implemented the suggested best practice. Following is the format of the prefix: `bucket-name/[First four of UUID]-[YYYYmmddhhiiss]/[random UUID]/[random UUID].json`. The method didn't work though.

Any idea how to overcome this error? Thank you!
P.S: I have requested the PUT limit increase to AWS Support center. They suggested the above steps which didn't work.

Comment: 10K PUT requests every second, continuously, would cost ~$129,600.00/month... so, what's your use case for such a large amount of traffic?

Comment: @michael-sqlbot The workflow is simple. Every request will create PUT request to S3. The number of requests per second will be around 10k. We are going to move to the batch system so we can decrease the PUT requests.

Comment: How many requests have you been able to successfully make, per second?  How long does this process last?  It obviously does not run 24 × 7 × 365, which is what "*every* second" implies.

Comment: The 10k RPS is expected requests per second on the production. It might not be constantly in 10k requests per second, but it will be around that.

Re: How many requests have you been able to successfully make
It is very hard to track that metric. I am going to find a way to track that.

Answer (score 6):

S3 is distributed, and you need to make sure that you don't create hotspots.  You can avoid this by ensuring that your object keys are truly random.

So move the [randome UUID] to the first part of your object key.  And if you're not generating truly random UUIDs, (i.e. it sounds like perhaps the first 4 characters are similar for each object) try reversing the UUID.

More tips can be found [here](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/3/7/scale-indefinitely-on-s3-with-these-secrets-of-the-s3-master.html)

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am going to decrease the S3 Put request by using batch system. Thanks for the link though, that is pretty useful.

Comment: If you are bursting to 10k request/sec, maybe look at pushing that load into a queue (SQS) and then distributing the load via processing nodes.

Comment: That will solve the problem! But unfortunately, adding another component into the workflow is not an option.

Comment: Note that since 2018, this has changed regarding random prefixing. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/